# Pythonic way of filtering by descendant element in a dictionary

Tags: python

If I have some json data represented in a dictionary type, what's the pythonic way of finding all 'type' nodes that match a particular value from the 'results' list of items?

```
"results" : [
   {
      "address_components" : [
         ... child elements ...
      ],
      "verified" : "some data here",
      "geometry" : {
         ... child elements ...
      },
      "types" : [ "type_one" ]
   },

   {
      "address_components" : [
         ... child elements ...
      ],
      "verified" : "some data here",
      "geometry" : {
         ... child elements ...
      },
      "types" : [ "type_two" ] // filter all items that match this item's value
   },
   ... more elements ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
foundItems = [elem for elem in results if 'type_two' in elem['types']]
```

Of course you'll probably use a variable instead of hard-coding `'type_two'` like that.

This will allow other values in the `types` list alongside the one you are looking for. You can use `if elem['types'] == ['type_two']` instead to look for that specific value only.

Comment: In many cases, it's preferable to use a generator expression over a list comprehension. A generator expression finds the values as you iterate over it rather than making a whole list ahead of time.

A generator expression looks the same as a list comprehension, except that it uses parens instead of brackets -- `(elem for elem in results if 'type_two' in elem['types'])`. If you pass a generator expression as the only argument to a function, the redundant parens can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_type(results, search_type):
    matching_results = []
    for result in results:
        if search_type in result["types"]:
            matching_results.append(result)
    return matching_results
```

Comment: `function` is not a Python keyword(PHP, I think), it should be `def`. And `result["types"].count(search_type) > 0` instead of a simple `in` lookup is an awful idea.